# Actionscript 3, addChild to stage and addEventListener not working together

Tags: actionscript-3, addeventlistener, addchild

I just wanna add an image from my library on the stage and have an event listener on it so when i click on it, it will do something. imgFromMyLib is already set to the image i want from my library. Please help. What is the easiest way to do this ?

```
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.display.Sprite;


function pwned(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
        trace ("a");
}

var myImg:imgFromMyLib = new imgFromMyLib();
var myBitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(myImg);
myBitmap.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, pwned);
addChild(myBitmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myImg:imgFromMyLib = new imgFromMyLib(0,0);
var myBitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(myImg);
var mc:MovieClip =  new MovieClip();
mc.graphics.beginFill(0x333333,1);
mc.graphics.drawRect(0,0,myBitmap.width, myBitmap.height);
mc.graphics.endFill();
addChild(mc);
mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, pwned);
mc.addChild(myBitmap);

function pwned(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
        trace ("a");
}
```

try this....

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the symbol you're trying to import is a graphic, and so subclasses BitmapData, you must pass its required dimensions in it's constructor:

```
var myImg:imgFromMyLib = new imgFromMyLib(100,100); // replace with real dimensions
```